# How can I get a bulb shutter speed on a Canon 750D (Rebel T6i)?

Tags: dslr

How can I set the shutter speed to "bulb" on a Canon EOS 750D (Rebel T6i)?

Comment: Can you reword your question so that it's comprehensible? Have you checked your manual?

Answer (score 5):

> How can I get a bulb shutter speed on a Canon 750D (T6i)?

- Put the mode dial in **M** mode for Manual Exposure Mode.
- Select ISO and aperture manually. Hold down the [Av+/-] button while turning the main dial to set aperture.
- Set the shutter time by rotating the main dial to the left. The 'Bulb' setting is just past the setting for 30" (thirty seconds).

In 'Bulb' mode the exposure meter will not give a reading, since the camera has no way of knowing how long you plan on holding the shutter open. 'Auto ISO' is also not available in 'Bulb' mode for the same reason.

It's all covered on pages 155 and 156 of the [*EOS Rebel T6i / EOS 750D Instruction Manual*](https://media.the-digital-picture.com/Owners-Manuals/Canon-EOS-Rebel-T6i.pdf).

[image: Manual p.155]

[image: Manual p.156]

Although a tripod and a remote shutter release/timer are recommended, they are not required to use the 'Bulb' setting.

A wired shutter release functions *exactly* the same as the shutter button except that you don't need to actually touch the camera to open the shutter and hold it open. Most wired remotes have a button lock that allows the shutter button to be held down without having to continuously press the shutter release button. To use a wired release, just plug it in. That's it. Both the camera's and the wired remote's shutter button will function identically.

Although the functionality of combining the wireless remote with bulb mode is not covered in depth in the [*Instruction Manual*](https://media.the-digital-picture.com/Owners-Manuals/Canon-EOS-Rebel-T6i.pdf), it is possible to do so with the EOS Rebel T6i/750D. For Canon cameras that do have such functionality available, do the following:

If you want to use a wireless remote RC-6 with 'Bulb' mode (Please see page 350 of the [*Instruction Manual*](https://media.the-digital-picture.com/Owners-Manuals/Canon-EOS-Rebel-T6i.pdf)), set the 'Drive Mode' to 'Self Timer' (page 114 of the [*Instruction Manual*](https://media.the-digital-picture.com/Owners-Manuals/Canon-EOS-Rebel-T6i.pdf)) and press the button fully once to open the shutter and again to close it. Unlike with other shutter time settings, when the shutter time (Tv) is set to 'Bulb', there will be no delay between pressing the button on the remote and the camera's shutter opening in the regular "10 second delay" self-timer 'Drive Mode'. If 'Drive Mode' is set to the 2 second self-timer setting, there will be a two second delay before the shutter opens. With the wireless remote the camera will automatically close the shutter after 30 minutes if you do not press the button in the remote again.