# EOS 750D bulb mode behaves differently depending on live-view. Is this a bug, a feature or am I missing something?

Tags: canon, live-view, bulb-mode

The bulb mode of my EOS 750D works as expected only when the camera is in live-view. Then, the shutter opens as long as the shutter button is pressed and closes on release of the button (see also manual p. 156). When not in live-view, I have to press the button once to open the shutter and again to close it. The same is true when I use my TW-282 remote timer, which leads to strange effects, like the shutter opens only at the end of every odd exposure - and keeps open all the time until the end of the next even exposure. I would like to know if this is a known bug or a feature or whether I'm simply missing something. Obviously, I was not able to test all possible combinations, but as far as it went, I was not able to find any relationship with any of the other settings of the camera. Is there a way to use "regular" bulb mode without having to switch to live-view? Do other EOS 750D owners see the same behavior?
Thanks!
Pat

Comment: For me what you describe is the difference between [B mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulb_(photography)) (keep the shutter pressed) and T mode (a press at start and end).

Comment: are you running magic lantern?

Comment: @dandavis: No, I have the original FW. The camera just does not behave like described in the manual. Or so I think...

Comment: @xenoid: That's right! Just that the 750D has neither B- nor T-mode (on the dial). It has only M-mode, which switches to "B" when you go past 30". But then, it seems, the behavior depends on whether live-view is on or not. Which I find strange!

Comment: I don't have time to look now, but I seem to remember that B-mode/T-mode was an option set using custom functions on an EOS so old it didn't have live view.  Perhaps digging around in the custom functions for your model may be instructive - look online for documentation and then have a play.  OTOH I could be misremembering

Comment: ... I can't find such a setting for your model, anyway. See also [this answer to *How can I get a bulb shutter speed on a Canon 750D (Rebel T6i)?*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/98434/26575) which has a manual quote that implies different behaviour with a remote and with the internal shutter button (but doesn't mention live view).

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for looking into this. I found about the same information. I might check on some astrophotography sites, if somebody can suggest how to use an interval timer on the EOS 750D. In the worst case, I have to use live-view. Unfortunately that is not so good for the batteries, when on a remote site...

Comment: @Pat interval timers should be easy enough.  There are some pretty versatile ones out there (I haven't used them but I've [played with triggering using a custom adaptor and Python code](https://github.com/ChrisHodgesUK/mtrigger) myself.  That would adapt for long exposures.)

Comment: @Chris: :-) Yes, I know. It's just that I have two interval timers already. One with and one without cable. Would have been nice to just use them "out-of-the-box" as I did years ago all the time with my old EOS 1100D... Thanks anyway!